# Jquery XML Audio Tag

Tags: jquery, xml, audio

I'm trying to have a jquery script add things onto a webpage. I can get pictures and text but I want there to be audio tags for songs.

```
$(this).find("song").each(function(){
  $("#d" + n).append("<audio src='" + $(this).attr("url") + "' controls>
    <embed src='" + $(this).attr("url") + "' 
    width="300" 
    height="90" 
    loop="false"  
    autostart="false" />
  </audio><br>" );
});
```

When I try it this way I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

The error says its on the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove the error message you are getting. Change width, height, loop and autostart to single quotes instead of double. Also make it so all the embed tag attributes are in the same line, currently they span across multiple lines.

Comment: This would be better with an explanation of why those fix things, as opposed to encouraging cargo cult programming.